# Python3: convert apostrophe unicode string

Tags: python-3.x, unicode-string, unicode-escapes

I have a string value with an apostrophe like this:

```
"I\\xE2\\x80\\x99m going now."
```

How can I get correct apostrophe value?

```
"I`m going now."
```

As you know, `\xE2\x80\x99` is the a unicode character `U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`, but I have a string representation instead of byte...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
utf8_apostrophe = b'\xe2\x80\x99'.decode("utf8")
str = "I"+utf8_apostrophe+"m going now"
```

Aside:
I ran into this when converting a single quotation mark, within a UTF-8-encoded tweet, into a normal single quote.

```
import re
original_tweet = 'I’m going now'
string_apostrophe = "'"
print re.sub(utf8_apostrophe, string_apostrophe, original_tweet)
```

which produces

```
I'm going now
```